# CakePHP-Bootstrap collapse doesn't work

Tags: html, css, cakephp-3.0

Hi I'm trying to make bootstrap work in my cakephp project. I'm just starting to learn cake and I dont know why my collapse doesnt work.

In my `webroot\css\` i have my `bootstrap.css` file. In my `webroot\js` i have `bootstrap.min.js`, `collapse.js`, `transition.js` files.

In my `src\Template\Layout\default.ctp` i wrote

```
<?= $this->Html->css('bootstrap') ?>
<?= $this->Html->script(['bootstrap.min','collapse','transition']) ?>
```

and on the `<body>` tag i wrote...

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" >
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
   </button>
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bookmarks</a>
  </div>
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class=""><a href="#">Add Bookmarks</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Export Data Modified</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="logout.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</nav>
```

But everytime I test the collapse by making my browser smaller. When I click the "burger" the items don't come out. Any idea why?

Comment: did you include jquery before bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

Your not closing your nav tag or did you just forget to post it?

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing it, It works for me. Look for the console error messages. This may be due to the loading of css, script files.May be your server doesnt support `<?= ?>` tags. Try using `<?php ?>` tags. And Please tell what are the error messages which you get, when something is not working. So that it will be easier for anyone to debug.

Comment: actually there are no error messages it just doesnt work when I click it. thanks ill try your suggestion